# Kotlin, Proguard and lambdas

Tags: android, lambda, proguard, kotlin

I have a neat function that does something on a view:

```
fun<T : View> Activity.withView(nr : Int, fn : T.()->Unit) {
    (findViewById(nr) as T?)?.fn()
}
```

Now, when I use this function in my activity:

```
    withView<Spinner>(R.id.spinner_toolbar) {
        adapter = AdapterIndeksuDlaSpinnera(this@NewMainActivity, PlaylistIndex)
```

...everything is OK until I use ProGuard. I can see `AdapterIndeksuDlaSpinnera` gets mangled, as expected, but the application fails when proguarded with "Can't load class AdapterIndeksuDlaSpinnera" (while it should complain about mangled adapter name).

I was able to create temporaty workaround by disabling mangling of all adapters that can be used inside my `withView`

```
-keep class pl.qus.xenoamp.adapter.** { *; }
```

but I don't feel it's a good solution (and I have no idea what other classes can fail this way!). So can anyone explain what is the problem and what ProGuard line should I add to potentially fix similar occurences of other classes used inside `withView`?

Comment: Could you please post `.class` file for the adapter as well as the file, containing the closure? They can be found in `build/intermediates/classes/` of the Android project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103964/discussion-between-user1643723-and-ssuukk).

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one. In nutshell, Proguard does not know about Kotlin. It is using a simple code analysis to detect things like `Class.forName()` and work around them, but may fail for anything more complex. You need to look at generated `.class` files from `build` subdirectories (can you post relevant ones?) to find out what really happens.

For now you can do two things:

- Ask Kotlin devs to add proper obfuscation/optimization support to the Kotlin compiler: this is really *the right way* to do things, as demonstrated by every non-java compiler in existence;
- Exclude your own sources from obfuscation (most Activities and Views aren't going to be well-obfuscated anyway).

Comment: You can add a feature request for things like obfuscation at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com ... be sure to include the difficulty of post-compilation obfuscaters in knowing what is safe or not given only the class file.  (but then again, it is hard to obfuscate without knowing uses outside of a current compilation module as well, so a compile-time version could have problems as well, just different ones)